# Python: how select pandas rows based on condition on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     city   val
0   London   3
1   London   -1
2   London   -1
3   Paris    -5
4   Paris    -2
5   Rome     2
6   Rome     2
```

I want to select only the city that have at least one `val < 0`. I would like to have the following:

```
df
     city   val
0   London   3
1   London   -1
2   London   -1
3   Paris    -5
4   Paris    -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Create mask and filter rows with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df[df['val'].lt(1).groupby(df['city']).transform('any')]
print (df)
     city  val
0  London    3
1  London   -1
2  London   -1
3   Paris   -5
4   Paris   -2
```

Or filter `city` with at least one row match less like `1` and filter original `city` column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['city'].isin(df.loc[df['val'].lt(1), 'city'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` with `groupby` and `.transform(min)`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('city')['val'].transform(min).lt(0)]
     city  val
0  London    3
1  London   -1
2  London   -1
3   Paris   -5
4   Paris   -2
>>>
```

Since you're filtering under 0, just filter if the minimum value of each group is lower than 0.